# Evolution of Stack (Exchange) leadership

Tags: discussion, moderation, stack-exchange, community

If you're a regular reader of RPG meta, this post over on Meta.SE might interest/concern you:

[Changing how community leadership works on Stack Exchange: a proposal and rough timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396924/311001)

I post this just as an FYI; I don't think there's anything *specific to RPG* implicated.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I can only say that it didn't give me a feel good moment.